# Mining from multiple servers to local wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mining, cpu-mining

I am mining using *./monerod* on Windows 10. I have created a wallet using *monero-wallet-cli.*

I want to setup more machines that run *./monerod*.   How can I set them up so they mine to one wallet and not have to setup a new wallet on every machine?

Answer (score 1):

While monerod does the mining, it does not control/manage wallets, and just uses whatever wallet address the user tells it to.

Therefore, if you created one wallet with address A on some computer, any monerod can mine to that wallet address by giving A to the start_mining command, ie:

`start_mining A 3`

This will start mining to wallet A with three threads.

Wallet A could well have been created on an offline computer. The public keys represented by the address are enough to mine to it.

Comment: just to confirm understanding, is this the long address  so the command would be something like (sanitised) 

start_mining  42X2yLJoHfyJU1htUMncWX9h8jahJ3WRp4bGuadinZVXPZAK6Foiy3JefyUnLCSRPjeoQgzdVtgKeQRBsHumaycHEng5T8u 3

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That same address can be given to any number of mining servers, and any monero found by any of them will end up on the wallet, so only one computer has to check the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You just specify the same wallet for every machine that is mining.

You have to specify the wallet you are mining to for every computer that you are mining on. And you can use the same wallet for each of these computers.

Comment: lets say I have server A with a local wallet named WalletA. If I have server B and try to open WalletA, it says it does not exist. How would I access Wallet A which is local to server A on server B?

Comment: you have to import the wallet also on server B. meaning you have to get the private key or mnemonic seed from the wallet on server A and import it on server B